# Can I use C++20 ranges to break when matched count is greater than some threshold?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

Consider the following pre ranges code:

```
std::vector<int> v(1000*1000);
bool count_gt_5_v1(int val){
    return std::count(v.begin(), v.end(), val)>5;
}
```

It looks nicer than the raw loop, but it can be very inefficient if val is very common in v.

Is there any way to use C++20 ranges so that iteration will stop after I encounter val 6 times.
In other words I am looking for a way to introduce a break when my condition is satisfied.
I have this abomination, that seems to work, but it is much much uglier than raw for loop.

```
bool count_gt_5_v2(int val){
    int cnt=0;
    auto span = std::ranges::views::take_while(v,[&cnt, &val]
    (const auto elem)
    {
        cnt+=elem==val; 
        return cnt<6;
    });
    std::ranges::distance(span);
    return cnt==6;
}
```

Link to  full code: https://godbolt.org/z/86djdK

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this:

```
auto matches = v | rv::filter([=](int i){ return i == val; })
                 | rv::take(6);
return ranges::distance(matches) == 6;
```

Or, better:

```
auto matches = v | rv::filter([=](int i){ return i == val; });
return not ranges::empty(matches | rv::drop(5));
```

---

This attempt:

```
std::ranges::views::take_while(v, [&cnt, &val](const auto elem){
    cnt+=elem==val; 
    return cnt<6;
});
```

doesn't meet the requirements of `take_while`. All of the predicates in ranges have to be *equality-preserving* - same inputs, same output. Here, that's not the case - if we call the predicate twice on a single element, we'd get different output. So that's undefined behavior.

Comment: You are saying that ranges do not have specified number of applications of a predicate like old algorithms do?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl I am saying that that is the requirement of all the constrained algorithms. `ranges::find_if` has the same requirement.

Comment: Still weird, I was expecting something similar to old algorithms, but Eric probably had a good reason to specify it like that...

Example of std::find_if
Complexity

At most last - first applications of the predicate